# How to use Firebase Serve without triggering my Firebase https Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have created a Firebase Function to server side render my website for SEO purposes.

However now when I use `firebase serve` or `firebase serve --except functions` the function is still triggered.

This means the only way I can test is by deploying and updating my https function.

Is there a way to test locally without triggering my function?

Answer (score 0):

You can serve functions locally with the command below;

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

This would serve your functions from `localhost:5000`. If you would like to serve this local version you can also use [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/) and test it with your front-end.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for testing without functions. As I mentioned I have tried `firebase serve --except functions` however  the function is still tirggered

Comment: How does your function triggered? Is it Realtime Database Triggered?

Comment: It's an HTTPS trigger

Comment: I'm a little confused. Did you mean deployed in this sentence? -However now when I use firebase serve or firebase serve --except functions the function is still triggered.-

Comment: I did not. When I use `firebsae serve --except functions`, the HTTP function is still triggered on localhost

Comment: For testing I init a new project with hosting and functions. I created a helloworld http function and then used the `firebase serve` to test. firebase just served the hosting and not functions. Then I opened up a new cmd and run `firebase serve --only functions --port 5005`. Now my hosting is at `localhost:5000` and functions are at `localhost:5005`. Hope this helps. By the way please be sure to use latest firebase-tools.